C# `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` hangs unless process is killed
I'm trying to build an Excel add-in that'll let the user invoke R commands in cells. Something like BERT, except that BERT uses its own R environment independent of the environment actually installed on your machine; and since BERT's development halted sometime in 2018, newer R packages that aren't backwards-compatible are a problem.
The step I'm tring to make right now is to build a C# app that just sends the user input to R.exe, and relays R's output to the console. The catch is that I don't want to kill the R process after each calculation; I want it to be running in the background so any data that is imported into R stays in memory for the next calculation.
I use System.IO.StreamReader and System.IO.StreamWriter classes for redirecting the output and input. If there is no output from R (such as when a variable is defined, say a=0), attempting a reader.ReadLine() just hangs the app. I assume it's waiting indefinitely for some output from R, which never comes. The same happens whenever any of the following is invoked: reader.ReadToEnd(), reader.EndOfStream. Basically, I have no way of telling if I've read all output yet or not.
That's how I start the process (I tried both R.exe and Rterm.exe but that doesn't seem to make any difference):
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.3\bin\x64\Rterm.exe",
            Arguments = "--vanilla --slave",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        Process rProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);

Then define the streams:
            StreamReader reader = rProcess.StandardOutput;
            StreamWriter writer = rProcess.StandardInput;

I writer.Flush() the stream after writing to it.
Of course, if I rProcess.Kill() it, the stream somehow gets closed and can be read until the end, but that's not what I want. If I close the stream via reader.Close(), I can't read it. I even tried to see how this communication is done in RStudio by examining the code but that's too complicated for a newbie like me.

Either inject some kind of echo command into the input to act as a command boundary, or close the input.

I thought of that, basically make R print a 'null character' after each output (much like C terminates character strings) to signify output boundary. Could you elaborate more on what you mean by closing the input, though? Did you mean 'close the output'? And if so, how do I close it properly? Now, after closing it I get the "Can't read from a closed stream" error.

No, I mean that if you ran R interactively, it would probably terminate when it had completed processing the last command and its stdin was closed, indicating no further input commands, triggering a graceful shutdown.

Okay, I wrote another comment, but first let me make sure I understand you correctly. You're saying that if I ran R interactively (I found out there's a switch for that, ha), then it would shut down and close its output stream, allowing the parent process to read it till the end? I don't want R to terminate, though. I want it to stay in memory with all the data it has loaded. Or am I missing something?

I would expect R to keep trying to read new commands, until you close the input, and only then would R close its output. Until which time your attempt to read from the output would block, explaining the behaviour you have already seen. If you want to reuse the same R instance, and need to correlate the output with the input, you'll need R to write some kind of delimiter you can easily identify. If you aren't compiling your own R, you need to write some print command (or something, I dunno) to the input, so you can read it back out.

Yes, I see, this is certainly sound reasoning. I can confirm that if I close the input stream with writer.Close(), R closes its output stream and I can read it. Then of course I can't input any more commands, alas. Yes, I think the delimiter injection method is my only hope right now. I'm just wondering whether it's good programming practice (what if some future data accidentally happens to include my delimiter?) but I sure need to work with what I have.

Which is why you pick a delimiter that is unlikely, like \r\n--something-{id}--\r\n.
